# Express4: Storing db instance

Tags: node.js, express

In express4, is it bad practice to store the db instance in app.locals or store it using app.set? Because I was thinking about it, since I will need it throughout my app it will be easier to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work just fine and no, I don't think it's bad practice (at least not *horrible*) - after all, `app.locals` is intended to provide you a safe place to put your global values.

However, using Express to store miscellaneous global values like this does result in your application being tightly bound to Express. If you ever decide that you want to remove Express and replace it with something else, you're going to have to hunt down and change all those references to `app.local` that are now scattered throughout your code.

If you want to avoid this, one simple pattern is to create a module exporting the value you want - this allows you to keep all the associated code in one place and import it whenever you need it. For example:

```
// modules/database.js

// initialize the database
const db = initializeDatabase();

// export a "getter" for the database instance
export const get = () => db;
```

Then, when you want to use the database instance:

```
// index.js

// import the database "getter"
import { get } from './modules/database';

// perform a query
const rows = get().query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

Just import `modules/database` anywhere you want to use the database.